# I can't seem to change the window form text in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio to create a program. So far, it has one window with a button.

in Form1.Designer.cs, it initializes the window:

```
namespace Test
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // I took out everything else, it isn't needed.

        // 
        // formMain
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(624, 442);
        this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
        this.Name = "formMain";
        this.Text = "Program Name";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.formMain_Load);
        this.menuBar.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.menuBar.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
}
```

In Form1.cs:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formMain.ActiveForm.Text = formMain.ActiveForm.Text + " - Project Name";
    }
```

...but it doesn't change the window text after I click the button. I've also tried `formMain.ActiveForm.Refresh()` after changing the text, but that didn't work. I've search high and low for a solution, but I'm new to C#. Do any of you have any ideas for me?

Comment: What does "I took everything out" mean?  You also took out the code that registers the button1_Click event handler?  Don't edit the designer-generated code.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like that?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = "Works!";
}
```

Comment: No, don't touch the designer file. The handler for your button click belongs to `Form1.cs`, just like you correctly wrote in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, never edit `designer.cs` code. This is auto-generated and you can break things if you edit the file.

Second, with the code you showed us `formMain` has not been initialized to anything so it will error out of you try to set properties (such as its Text property). So you have two options:

1. Set `formMain` to your form (not recommended due to the next option)
2. Use the `this` object. `this` refers to the current object you are working with (in this case you are referring to your form).

You can set the form's Text property to change the form's title. For example:

```
this.Text = "Hello World!";
```